# Две сетевые карты. Одна пашет, другая нет

Tags: ubuntu, сервер, сеть

Стучу первой картой нормально :

```
$ ping -I enp2s0 192.168.0.160
PING 192.168.0.160 (192.168.0.160) from 192.168.0.72 enp2s0: 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 192.168.0.160: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.338 ms
```

Стучу второй тишина :

```
$ ping -I enp3s0 192.168.0.160
PING 192.168.0.160 (192.168.0.160) from 192.168.0.65 enp3s0: 56(84) bytes of data.
^C
--- 192.168.0.160 ping statistics ---
5 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 4097ms
```

ipv6 проходит :

```
$ ping -I enp3s0 fe80::94a1:4767:1eb0:555d
PING fe80::94a1:4767:1eb0:555d(fe80::94a1:4767:1eb0:555d) from fe80::523e:aaff:fe16:8646%enp3s0 enp3s0: 56 data bytes
64 bytes from fe80::94a1:4767:1eb0:555d%enp3s0: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.331 ms
```

Входящий стук ipv4 то проходит, то нет :

```
$ ping -I eth1 192.168.0.65              
PING 192.168.0.65 (192.168.0.65) from 192.168.0.160 eth1: 56(84) bytes of data.
^C
--- 192.168.0.65 ping statistics ---
7 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 6137ms
```

или

```
$ ping -I eth1 192.168.0.65
PING 192.168.0.65 (192.168.0.65) from 192.168.0.160 eth1: 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 192.168.0.65: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.180 ms
```

Входящий ipv6 нормальный :

```
$ ping6 -I eth1 fe80::523e:aaff:fe16:8646
PING fe80::523e:aaff:fe16:8646(fe80::523e:aaff:fe16:8646) from fe80::94a1:4767:1eb0:555d%eth1 eth1: 56 data bytes
64 bytes from fe80::523e:aaff:fe16:8646%eth1: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.312 ms
```

Что-то я неправильно настроил. Укажите, пожалуйста причину. И как исправить.

$ ip ad

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp2s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether c8:60:00:61:62:c3 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.0.72/24 brd 192.168.0.255 scope global enp2s0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 2a03:e2c0:bde:5555:ca60:ff:fe61:62c3/64 scope global dynamic mngtmpaddr noprefixroute 
       valid_lft 2591906sec preferred_lft 604706sec
    inet6 2a03:e2c0:bde:5555::5/64 scope global 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::ca60:ff:fe61:62c3/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: enp3s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 50:3e:aa:16:86:46 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.0.65/24 brd 192.168.0.255 scope global enp3s0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 2a03:e2c0:bde:5555:523e:aaff:fe16:8646/64 scope global dynamic mngtmpaddr noprefixroute 
       valid_lft 2591906sec preferred_lft 604706sec
    inet6 fe80::523e:aaff:fe16:8646/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::230:4fff:fe40:709/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
4: wlp4s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 6c:6a:77:30:9d:5a brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

$ ip route

```
default via 192.168.0.1 dev enp2s0 proto static 
default via 192.168.0.1 dev enp3s0 proto static 
default via 192.168.0.1 dev enp3s0 proto static metric 100 
192.168.0.0/24 dev enp2s0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.0.72 
192.168.0.0/24 dev enp3s0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.0.65 
192.168.0.0/24 via 192.168.0.1 dev enp2s0 proto static metric 50
```

$ ip l

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
2: enp2s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether c8:60:00:61:62:c3 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: enp3s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 50:3e:aa:16:86:46 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
4: wlp4s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 6c:6a:77:30:9d:5a brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

$ cat /etc/netplan/50-cloud-init.yaml

```
    ethernets:
        enp2s0:
            addresses: [192.168.0.72/24,"2a03:e2c0:bde:5555::5/64"]
            gateway4: 192.168.0.1
            nameservers:
              addresses: [8.8.8.8,8.8.4.4,"2001:4860:4860::8888","2001:4860:4860::8844"]
            dhcp4: no
            routes:
              - to: 192.168.0.0/24
                via: 192.168.0.1
                metric: 50
        enp3s0:
            addresses: [192.168.0.65/24, "fe80::523e:aaff:fe16:8646/64", "2a03:e2c0:bde:5555:523e:aaff:fe16:8646/64"]
            gateway6: "2a03:e2c0:bde::1"
            dhcp4: no
            gateway4: 192.168.0.1
            nameservers:
              addresses: [8.8.8.8,8.8.4.4,"2001:4860:4860::8888","2001:4860:4860::8844"]
            dhcp6: no
            routes:
              - to: 0.0.0.0/0
                via: 192.168.0.1
                metric: 100
  version: 2
```

После ответа **gbg** временное решение :

```
# оставил только ipv6
        enp3s0:
            addresses: [ "fe80::523e:aaff:fe16:8646/64", "2a03:e2c0:bde:5555:523e:aaff:fe16:8646/64"]
            gateway6: "2a03:e2c0:bde::1"
            nameservers:
              addresses: ["2001:4860:4860::8888","2001:4860:4860::8844"]
            dhcp6: no
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Одна и та же сеть `192.168.0.0/24` задана на двух адаптерах - это работать не будет. Чтобы осуществить такое, понадобится настроить агрегацию портов как на коммутаторе, так и на машине с линуксом.

Comment: Ну а если временно оставить только ipv6. Как сделать route по этим адресам?

Comment: @AlexGlebe - попробуйте метрики разные задать разве что

Comment: В одну сеть это временно... Потом кину на провайдера. Пока решил юзать ipv6.